# Click CLI works using script but not when packaged due to path error

Tags: python, command-line-interface

: )

As I finished working on my CLI .. it works perfectly as a script.however, I wanted to push it to PyPi and be able to distribute it via pip.

When running it locally.. it works like a charm. All my functions.,

for instance: - `python main.py fuzz -p example.com` 
But.. when installing the package locally & and running the CLI via:

- `pip install -e .`

It works for everything but the functions that use a list.txt.

for instance, it works for me when running:

- `kitsec cve python -l 2`

But not when running:

-- `kitsec fuzz domain.com`

It returns this error `../lists/fuzz/path_fuzz/ does not exist`

Any Idea? My source code is [here](https://github.com/kitsec-labs/kitsec-core).

Thanks!

I tried running the same function while packaged. but it failed to recognize the path.